# Generic function with same logic but different input structure

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
interface Node {
  originalWeight: number;
  currentWeight: number;
}
```

where both properties are floats between `0` and `1`.

To check if a node has been modified, I wrote a simple `isNodeModified` function:

```
isNodeModified(node: Node): boolean {
  return Math.abs(node.originalWeight- node.currentWeight) > this.EPSILON;
}
```

where `EPSILON` is my tolerance.

However, I also need to do a very similar comparison in a slightly different scenario, which was originally handled like this:

```
if (Math.abs(event.value - node.originalWeight) > this.EPSILON) {
  // do something
}
```

where `event` is another object with a `value` property.

To avoid duplication, I replaced both methods with something like the following:

```
isNodeModified(node: Node, event?: Event): boolean {
  let original = node.originalWeight;
  if (event) {
    original = event.value;
  }
  return Math.abs(original - node.currentWeight) > this.EPSILON;
}
```

So that I can call `isNodeModified(node)` or `isNodeModified(node, event)` depending on what I need.

Is there a better / cleaner solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what the purpose of `event` is?

Comment: @Adam it carries a value that will become the new `originalWeight`, but only if `event.value !== currentWeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most concise way to write your function that's still very readable is this:

```
function isNodeModified(node: Node, event?: Event): boolean {
  return Math.abs((event ? event.value : node.originalWeight) - node.currentWeight) > this.EPSILON;
}
```

If `event` is passed in, the `event`'s `value` is used, otherwise `node`'s `originalWeight` is used.

Ternary operators are amazing for condensing simple checks/if-statements into an inline operation. I recommend using them as much as possible as long as the result is still readable and not lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a more general function which simple compares two values.
Like:

```
hasDifference(oldValue: number, newValue: number, offset?: number): boolean {
  const offsetToUse: number = offset === undefined ? this.EPSILON : offset;

  return Math.abs(oldValue - newValue) > offsetToUse;
}
```

Comment: `offset?: number` is better than `offset: number | undefined` as the second requires calling as `hasDifference(oldV, newV, undefined)` (assuming you have strict null checks on, which you should)

Comment: changed it. @Gerrit0 - would that make `hasDifference(oldV, newV, null)` fail the `===` check?

Comment: `null !== undefined` so yes. If you have strict null checks on though, Typescript will complain at compile time.